# Quick question proving equivalence between statements involving subsets and bilinear forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Suppose we assign in $V$ (vector space) a bilinear symmetrical form $b$. Let $S$ be a subspace of $V$, $S^{\bot} := \{ w \in V \mid b(v,w) = 0\ \forall w \in S   \}$

Two subspaces $U$ and $W$ are said to be orthogonal if $U \subset W^{\bot}$ and this is equivalent to $W \subset U^{\bot}$.

Could someone spell the proof of this equivalence out for me I can't seem to see it.

Comment: what book are you reading?

Comment: @WillJagy It's in italian, it's Geometria 1 By Sernesi, he leaves the proof to the reader. Maybe a good hint could help me.

Comment: either way of writing it says that for every pair $u \in U, w \in W,$ we get $b(u,w) = 0.$ This uses symmetry of $b,$ because one way says $b(u,w) = 0,$ the other says $b(w,u)=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $U \subset W^\perp$.

If $w \in W$ and $u \in U$ then $b(w,u) = 0$ because $u \in W^\perp$. Thus $b(w,u) = 0$ for all $u \in U$, so that $w \in U^\perp$. It follows that $W \subset U^\perp$.